# var == False or if not var

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-expression

```
var = False
if not var:
    do_thing()
```

or

```
var = False
if var == False:
    do_thing()
```

What is the difference between the two?(If there is one)
Is one fast than the either?

Comment: there's no practical difference; if you're interested in a super-precise analysis, you can use [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to see exactly how they each evaluate

Comment: @user202729: This is about a boolean, not a string.

Comment: The difference is that `not var` is readable and what people expect you to use, whereas `var == False` makes people wonder whether there’s some other falsy value you explicitly want to exclude by not using `not` (but not `0`, because `0 == False`).

Comment: The differences start when your input is not a boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [PEP8 "Programming Recommendations"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.
>
> - Yes:   `if greeting:`
> - No:    `if greeting == True:`
> - Worse: `if greeting is True:`

Both of your tests happen to work here, but in general, using the implicit booleanness is considered more "Pythonic", since "truthy" vs. "falsy" is usually more important than `True` vs. `False`; `if not var:` will accurately identify `var` as falsy when it is `None`, or an empty sequence, which is usually what you want.

As far as performance goes, `if not var:` will be faster; `if var == False:` must load `var` and `False`, perform the comparison, then perform the implicit boolean test that `if` always performs; `if not var:` performs the implicit boolean test directly with no preamble.